# How to obtain Appell's PDEs from GKZ-equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function, differential-algebra

In F. Beukers' [Notes on A-Hypergeometric functions](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~beuke106/AHGcourse.pdf)
on p. 17, the Appell hypergeometric PDEs are derived from the GKZ-Equations
\begin{align*}
\partial_{1}\partial_{2}\Phi-\partial_{4}\partial_{5}\Phi & =0,\partial_{1}\partial_{3}\Phi-\partial_{4}\partial_{6}\Phi=0
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
(v_{1}\partial_{1}+v_{5}\partial_{5}+v_{6}\partial_{6}+a)\Phi & =0\\
(v_{2}\partial_{2}+v_{5}\partial_{5}+b)\Phi & =0\\
(v_{3}\partial_{3}+v_{6}\partial_{6}+b')\Phi & =0\\
(v_{4}\partial_{4}-v_{5}\partial_{5}-v_{6}\partial_{6}+1-c)\Phi & =0.
\end{align*}
The passage from the mentioned text I do not understand much is the
one below these equations:

''Let $\mathcal{Z}$ be the left ideal in $K[\partial_{1},...,\partial_{6}]$
generated by the operators $Z_{1},...,Z_{4}$ (here $K=C(v_{1},...,v_{6})$).
Consider for each box operator $\square$ the intersection of the
class $\square(\mod\mathcal{Z})$ with $K[\partial_{5},\partial_{6}]$
and set $v_{1}=\cdot\cdot\cdot=v_{4}=1,v_{5}=x,v_{6}=y$.

We obtain the classical differential equations 
\begin{align*}
x(1-x)F_{xx}+y(1-x)F_{xy}+(c-(a+b+1)x)F_{x}-byF_{y}-abF & =0\\
y(1-y)F_{yy}+x(1-y)F_{xy}+(c-(a+b'+1)y)F_{y}-b'xF_{x}-ab'F & =0.
\end{align*}
''

Here, $K$ is a differential field with commuting derivations $\partial_{i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial v_{i}}$
for $i=1,...,N$, the box operator

\begin{align*}
\square_{l}\Phi: & =\prod_{l_{i}>0}\partial_{i}^{l_{i}}\Phi-\prod_{l_{i}<0}\partial_{i}^{|l_{i}|}\Phi=0
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
Z_{i}\Phi: & =(a_{i1}v_{1}\partial_{1}+a_{i2}v_{2}\partial_{2}+\text{·}\text{·}\text{·}+a_{iN}v_{N}\partial_{N}-\alpha_{i})\Phi=0,\quad i=1,2,...,r\ .
\end{align*}

Can someone explain the very basic steps needed to derive Appell's
PDEs from these GKZ-equations? I am not yet familiar with abstract
algebra (nor with differential algebra).

I am physicist trying to understand whether the GKZ-functions help
me to solve linear second-order PDEs with polynomial coefficients
more general than the coefficients of Appell's PDEs. If this is the
case, I will invest more time to study these functions and the topic
of differential algebra.